# Should I use LaTeX3?

Tags: latex3

It is my current understanding that LaTeX3 is no longer conceived as a "new LaTeX", but as a maintenance and update program for the current LaTeX. That being said, I am wondering if I should be already using features of L3. For example, as of February 2022, the "source2e" documentation lists `\AtBeginDocument` as legacy LaTeX2e interface and recommends using `\AddToHook{begindocument}{<code>}` instead. Also, I can already see pieces of commands like `\AddToHook{env/quote/before}` and `\hook_if_empty_p:n`.

Considering that "source2e" has always been my main resource on current LaTeX syntax, it seems reasonable to use these new conventions. However, I am not 100% sure whether these are fully supported, encouraged, or otherwise.

As a related note, I am currently writing a LaTeX class for a journal and it will require LuaLaTeX for using system fonts. Is using this engine enough justification to use L3 syntax/conventions? Or, is L3 (or some of its features) still experimental and not recommended for production?

Thanks in advance for you answers!

Comment: Some things like the hooks are rather new and so won't work on older systems so the main question is not L3 or not but if you should use new commands or not.  Imho if you require lualatex you should also require a current tex system and so using new latex commands should be ok.

Comment: Regarding the L3 programming layer (aka `expl3`), it is, for the most part of it, stable for a long time now, so if you want to work on older systems, just do `\usepackage{expl3}`.  With the plus that on newer systems, it's preloaded in the kernel, so nothing extra needed

Comment: Just as LaTeX is built on top of TeX, LaTeX3 is built on top of LaTeX2.  In other words, all LaTeX3 code is translated into TeX or LaTeX2 before being executed.  If you compare the two, you will often find that the LaTeX3 code is longer and more complicated than the same code in LaTeX2.  So think of it as learning Klingon.

Comment: @JohnKormylo your statement is simply not true. The L3 programming layer is not build on top of 2e it is build on TeX primitives only, so 2e -> TeX primitives and L3 -> TeX primitives, not L3 -> 2e -> TeX primitives. Your other statement is also not true (in most cases) that the L3 code is longer and more complicated if you attempt to implement the same action is is mormally simply and shorter (it may execute more stuff, so \tracingall might be overwhelming, but that is a different topic).

Comment: @FrankMittelbach - Fewer lines, but each line is longer.  Algorithmically simpler, but syntactically more complex.